# Buscar todo el contenido de un archivo de texto

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, txt, awk

¿Cómo puedo buscar el contenido de un archivo de texto `1.txt` dentro de un archivo `2.txt` y las coincidencias relacionadas imprimirlas dentro de un nuevo archivo `nuevo.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v -f 1.txt 2.txt > nuevo.txt
```

Creo que es lo que estás buscando.

`-v` o `--invert-match` invierte el sentido del matching mostrando solo las lineas que no se encuentran en el match.

`-f` o `--file=FILE` indica que los patterns van a ser extraidos de un archivo

`2.txt` como segundo argumento, es el archivo contra el cual se efectúa el match de los patterns.

(con `man grep` se puede encontrar más información).

Comment: Podrías añadir algo de información extra explicando tu solución y por qué funciona.

Comment: editado, gracias por el aporte.